# Second Degree Friendship SQL -- Circular friendship issue

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the 2nd degree friendship from a table (tbl) with 2 columns (user | friend)

I can list out all the friends having 2nd degree friendship, but what if I need to exclude those that are first degree, I run into the circular friendship problem

ex.

```
user | friend
-------------
Doge | Cate

Cate | Narwhal

Narwhal | Doge
```

(and many more entries)

using `JOIN` on the same table by setting `t1.friend = t2.user`, I can find every trio that are connected through the middle man, but in this circular friendship example, I can't find a way to eliminate this. If I have

`Doge | Cate | Narwhal`

`Cate | Narwhal | Doge`

`Narwhal | Doge | Cate`

as my result of the commend, how to filter out this circular friendship and exclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
[user] VARCHAR(50),
Friend VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE ([user], friend)
VALUES ('Doge', 'Cate')

INSERT INTO @TABLE ([user], friend)
VALUES ('Cate', 'Narwhal')

INSERT INTO @TABLE ([user], friend)
VALUES ('Narwhal', 'Doge')

SELECT u.[user],  f.Friend, ff.*
FROM @TABLE u
    INNER JOIN @TABLE f         ON U.Friend = f.[user]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TABLE ff   ON u.[user] = ff.Friend 
                                AND f.Friend = ff.[user]
WHERE ff.[user] IS NULL
```

Comment: It's not exactly it but I figured out what I'm missing from your reply. It seems like I've been dealing with 2 tables only, and I'd need 3 in order to check of the circular friendship exists. The second `JOIN` solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    [SecondFriend].user
FROM tbl [self]
INNER JOIN tbl [FirstFriend] ON [FirstFriend].user=[self].friend
INNER JOIN tbl [SecondFriend] ON [SecondFriend].user=[FirstFriend].friend
    AND [SecondFriend].user <> [self].friend
WHERE [self].user='Doge'
```